# Why does ReadProcessMemory always return false?

Tags: c#

Don't know why but for some ReadProcessMemory always returns false. Always import it like this:

```
[DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(Kernel32.Path)]
[DllImport(Kernel32.Dll)]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

Here are the result of running `ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr HandleWithAllAccess, IntPtr ProcessBaseAddress, byte[] BufferSizeOf500, int TheSize500, IntPtr.Zero);`

https://preview.ibb.co/eK8189/Screenshot_890.png

`Note: just so people don't start asking unrelated questions, Kernel32 is a class with the dll name and the path where to find it`

Comment: `DllImport(.., SetLastError = true)`. Then `throw new Win32Exception()` will actually tell you why the function fails when it returns `FALSE`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms680553) also lists some reasons why it might fail.

Comment: 1) Doing `SetLastError = true` didn't throw any exceptions.

2) I forgot about `The function fails if the requested read operation crosses into an area of the process that is inaccessible.`, thats probably what happened.

Comment: `SetLastError = true` isn't supposed to return anything, nor will unmanaged functions automatically produce managed exceptions. It instructs the marshaller to capture the result of `SetLastError()` so it's accessible when you want to check details. `Win32Exception` calls this and formats a result message. It's a good idea to set this whenever a function documents "To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`."

Comment: Oh, ok. Will do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

The read operation crossed into a inaccessible area of the process, that's why it returned false. Thank you Jeroen Mostert for linking the documentation and I will set the `SetLastError` to true from now on.